# Iterate through collection attribute of object with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to implement [this](http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2012/04/30/spring-data-mongodb-cascade-save-on-dbref-objects/) solution in my code regarding cascading save in spring data mongodb. It works for normal class like this.

```
public class Test{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DBRef
    @CascadeSave
    private Contact contact;
}
```

But I have something like this.

```
public class Test{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DBRef
    @CascadeSave
    private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I want to change the code in the `listener` which is in the [link](http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2012/04/30/spring-data-mongodb-cascade-save-on-dbref-objects/) I have given to work with collections. I have tried several things and with no success. Apart from that, if there is another way accomplish this task, it would be appreciated, even though it is a separate question.

My listener code given below, which is not much difference to the example link.

```
public class CascadingMongoEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CascadingMongoEventListener.class);

@Autowired
private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

@Override
public void onBeforeConvert(final Object source) {
     ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(source.getClass(), new ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback() {

        public void doWith(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
            try {
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(DBRef.class) && field.isAnnotationPresent(CascadeSave.class)) {
                    final Object fieldValue = field.get(source);
                    if (fieldValue != null) {

                        if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                            Collection models = (Collection) fieldValue;
                            for (Object model : models) {
                               mongoOperations.save(model);
                            }
                        } else {
                            mongoOperations.save(fieldValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private static class DbRefFieldCallback implements ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback {
    private boolean idFound;

    public void doWith(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Id.class)) {
            idFound = true;
        }
    }

    public boolean isIdFound() {
        return idFound;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution which worked for me, I would appreciate any suggestion for improvements.

```
public class CascadingMongoEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CascadingMongoEventListener.class);
@Autowired
private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

@Override
public void onBeforeConvert(final Object source) {
    ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(source.getClass(), new ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback() {

        public void doWith(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);

            if (field != null) {
                Object fieldValue = field.get(source);
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(DBRef.class) && field.isAnnotationPresent(CascadeSave.class)) {
                    if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(fieldValue.getClass())) {
                        Collection<Object> collection = (Collection<Object>) fieldValue;
                        for (Object item : collection) {
                            if (mongoOperations.collectionExists(item.getClass())) {
                                mongoOperations.save(item);
                                logger.debug("Set of {}s saved.", item.getClass().getSimpleName());
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (mongoOperations.collectionExists(fieldValue.getClass())) {
                            mongoOperations.save(fieldValue);
                            logger.debug("{} saved.", fieldValue.getClass().getSimpleName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```